# Dynamically submit by specific language - JavaScript - React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a submit data when I change my actual language of the screen to another value, and I wondering the best way to be very clean and using React Hooks. right now I'm using something like that, but is to much code if I get every language that has in the world :(

someting.language will be the props with the 'pt' or 'en' or any language in the world

```
const titleValuePtProps = useSelector(something => something.language)

const titleValueEnProps = useSelector(something => something.language)

     useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedLanguage === 'pt') {
            setTitleValuePt(titleValuePtProps);
            setSelectedLanguage('pt')
        }
        if (selectedLanguage === 'en') {
         setTitleValueEn(titleValueEnProps);  
          setSelectedLanguage('en')
      
      }
    }, [selectedLanguage, city.id]);
    
    const save = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setSaving(true);
        let data;
         if (selectedLanguage === 'en') {
            data = {
                id: id,
                title: { da: titleValueEn },
                description: { da: descriptionValueEn},
                city: city.id,
             
            };
        }
        if (selectedLanguage === 'pt') {
            data = {
                id: id,
                title: { da: titleValueDa },
                description: { da: descriptionValuePt},
                city: city.id,
             
            };
        }

        dispatch(
            saveData(data, (response) => {
                dispatch(something({ id: 0, isOpen: false }));
              
            }),
        );
    };


return (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => save(e)}>
            <IntlInputLanguages
                languages={LANGUAGES}
                selectedLanguage={selectedLanguage}
                onChange={(l) => onLanguageChange(l)}
            />
            <TextField
                type="textarea"
                label="Title"
                value={supValue}
                onChange={(value) => {
                    setTitleValue(value);
                }}
            />
            <TextField
                type="textarea"
                label="Description"
                value={descriptionValue}
                onChange={(value) => {
                    setDescriptionValue(value);
                }}
            />
                <ButtonSave>Save</ButtonSave>
    </form>
);
}
```

Comment: what is useSelector, is this the full code?

Comment: useSelector is from react-redux, is the same thing like mapStateToProps. no it is not the full code.

Comment: Let's forget React, hooks and all that for a second: you can create an object: `someData = {}` and put data into it: `someData.en = { title: "English Title" };`. Now, you can simply refer to `someData[selectedLanguage].title` to get the title in the selected language, regardless of the currently selected language. Simply using a variable as key for a data object is what you seem to need here, not some React feature or the like.

Comment: I tried something like that, but with title[language], seems to be working :D

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to add all the data to a seperate file e.g. `data.json`

**data.json**

```
    [
     {
       "language" : "en",
       "id" : 1,
       "title" : "English"
     },
     {
       "language" : "pt",
       "id" : 2,
       "title" : "Some title"
     }
    ]
```

Import above data in your component like this:

```
import data from './data.json';
```

**Component.js:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  let languageData = data.find(item => item.language === selectedLanguage);
  // use languageData^ to do whatever you want to do further.
},[])
```

And on recieving props e.g `selectedLanguage = 'en'` filter through the data and assign that particular to your component `data` variable and dispatch your api call like you re doing already.
It will reduce your component code and data will be systematically managed in a seperate file.

Comment: Nice approach, the only change is that I'm using a state for the languageData, so setLanguage(languageData.value). thanks!

Comment: I did another adjustment, so, I created a spread for data and there I adjust all the changes in the language.